# Unexpected shutdown after upgrade to play framework 3.0 with ServerStoppedReason

Tags: java, scala, playframework

We just upgraded to Play Framework 3.0 with Pekko and some of nodes in production are shutting down randomly with the message

`Starting synchronous coordinated shutdown with ServerStoppedReason reason and 2147513000 milliseconds timeout`.

However, there's no explanation of what is triggering the shutdown. Is there any way to get more information about what's triggering the shut down? It's only happening to a subset the subset of our nodes that run some background Pekko actors in addition to the request handling, but ServerStoppedReason is a play signal so it seems like this must be coming from Play.

My original thought was maybe it was memory related, but reducing the memory limits actually caused it to happen less often. And I would expect to see some sort of error message if it was a memory issue (which I do when I turn the memory down low enough that it immediately crashes). Any ideas?

Comment: Based on [play unexpected shutdown](https://discuss.lightbend.com/t/unexpected-shutdown/6773) it could be related with memory as you said. Could you provide some log message to have more context? Have you checked how much memory was consumed by the container at that moment? Maybe check the events of the container?

Comment: The only relevant log line was the coordinated shut down line I included in the question. We're configuring the JVM with `-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=50` (on a 3G node) and JVM basically immediately expands to that. More detailed JVM profiling would be challenging in our prod environment.

Comment: With that little info is a bit hard to imagine what could be the root cause. Not sure if you have some dashboards that tells you how much memory is consumed during the shutdown and if you have the logs of the system beside the logs of the app. Another thing that you could try is to add some hooks in the [Coordinated Shutdown](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/3.0.x/Shutdown)

Comment: Not sure what as going on but upgrading to the next higher patch version when it came out resolved all the issues, so moving forward with a shrug.